# Docker Service - different number of replicas on nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 4 Docker nodes with same CPU/Memory configuration. Also i have a service with 4 replicas where 1 replica is on 1 node.

Now, i added 5th node with more CPU and Memory configuration. I scaled service via command:

`docker service scale webserver=5`

And now i have 5 replicas on 5 nodes. In this case, I will receive 1/5 of traffic to each node.

For example: If I will increase number to 8, the next 3 will be distributed randomly to all nodes. Is any way how I can set that this new (or percentage) replicas must be distributed to the new server only ?

- via constraints i set only nodes what must be used for service, but not about priority
- via placement-pref i set only priority where replicas will be start, but not how many of them

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You cant really decide this based on the current spec, but

the quick solution that comes to mind is to add labels to your nodes, e.g. node.location.west and node.location.east.

Then define 2 services which use the same image, env, etc

```
apps-node-west:
  deploy:
    replicas: 3
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.location == west


apps-node-east:
  deploy:
    replicas: 4
    placement:
      constraints:
        - node.location == east
```

This way you can decide by issuing labels to nodes, how many nodes per label (location, etc) you add to your swarm.

Combining this with "maximum replicas per node" --replicas-max-per-node you can make sure that nodes are not overloaded in a specific label (location).

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint